# gdal create GeoPDF from GeoTiff

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, geopdf

Using Python I have a program that makes a GeoTiff map by joining several maps and converting with [rgb2pct](http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/swig/python/scripts/rgb2pct.py).

This works perfect and when imported in QGIS georeferencing is OK.
However, I want also GeoPDF (small size en sending to non experts).
I use:

```
src_ds = gdal.Open(src)
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("PDF")
dst_ds = driver.CreateCopy(dst, src_ds, 1)
```

This gives a GeoPDF also OK in QGis. The maps are 4000x5200 px. and should when printed at 20px/mm (508 dpi) print as exactly 1:25000 fitting on A4.
I have tried a lot of options e.g.:

```
gdal.SetConfigOption("DPI", "4080")
gdal.SetConfigOption("WRITE_USERUNIT", "NO")
```

But to no avail.

How do I specify the correct dpi for the pdf. (pdfjam works perfect but geo info is lost)?

Comment: I have had the same problem too, a few years ago. I decided that Adobe Acrobat was broken :) I tried all sorts of options and tags in the PDF to force a size and resolution, but if insisted on scaling and printing what it wanted. I finally have up and printed from Acrobat by forcing to print to a specific size in the print dialog box.  This was the only path I knew to finally get my maps to print at 1:12000

Answer (score 2):

[-outsize xsize[%]|0 ysize[%]|0]  I do -outsize 60% 0  for scaling to a certain percentage of the original size.   Outsize is in pixels and lines unless '%' is attached in which case it is as a fraction of the input image size. Starting with GDAL 2.0, if one of the 2 values is set to 0, its value will be determined from the other one, while maintaining the aspect ratio of the source dataset.

Comment: Unfortunately -outsize resizes the embedded image in the sense that my 2000x2600 image becomes with 50% 1000x1300 and I wanted to retain the image resolution.

Comment: Whereas  gdal.SetConfigOption("DPI", "254") did not work I found that driver.CreateCopy(dst, src, 1, ['DPI=508]) does work as shown by pdfinfo output. A second issue is that it apears that Adobe reader seems to ignore the dpi setting. Evince, however, works fine, printing EXACTLY to the intended scale.